# jQuery ui sortable giving weird gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting an unexpected gap when using jQuery UI sortable. I have used it before and never saw this, am I missing something dumb?

I added the html placeholder that it adds and see no reason for the gap..

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raxBoJ

```
$('.tile-holder').sortable({
  grid: [129, 116],
  // forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  // forceHelperSize: true,
  opacity: 0.5,
  tolerance: "pointer"
});
```

Comment: use `float:left;` instead of `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Ahh duh, not even sure why I did it that way in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: @dm4web Please don't leave the question open by answering in comments...

Comment: @TJ OK. I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `float:left;` instead of `display: inline-block;`